# How to get current location when location does not change

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, location

Hello i am new to android development . I want to get my current Location but i need to wait for my listener start working . The problem is that i dont change position so the listener cant work (?) !

Here is the sample of my code

My listener :

```
 locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                textView.append(location.getLongitude() + "\n" + location.getLatitude() + "\n");
                // just monitoring
                lat = location.getLatitude();
                lng = location.getLongitude();

            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        };
```

and i request the updates on this

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 300, 0, locationListener);
```

So if i am not mistaken the gps will take the new position based on time (300ms) or based on distance which is 0 so its gonna work ?? Should i wait some time to start taking it? How long? more than 2 minutes?

I got wi-fi open and gps of course this is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Details" />
    <activity android:name=".LoginMenu" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity android:name=".Road" />
    <activity android:name=".LoopActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Pedestrians"></activity>
</application>
```

> Many Thanks in regards

Comment: Try changing the permission from `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` to `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`.

Comment: i got both of em . Do you mean to delete one ??